# Nareit indices representing underlying assets or traded REITS?

Tags: real-estate

I’m looking into using Nareit for my analysis but do not understand exactly what it is. From the website it sounds like the indices track the REIT returns… not the returns of the properties underlying the REITs.

Does Nareit track the underlying property returns, or does it track the returns of the REITs themselves? This would make a massive different since the REITs themselves are like stocks and not actual property.

Comment: Yes. I think what you are looking for is NCREIF (actual properties) not NAREIT (stocks of REITs) https://www.analystforum.com/t/ncreif-vs-nareit/51030

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I said yes I meant "NAREIT tracks the returns on the publicly traded stocks of Real Estate Investment Trusts". Which I think is not what you want (please clarify).

Comment: I think you’ve answered my question. To be sure, what I’m asking is  if Nareit tracks the returns of the actual properties the REITs hold OR if Nareit tracks the returns of the listed REITs. So Nareit is tracking the returns you would get assuming you go buy REITs on an exchange, and NOT the returns you would get by investing in the underlying property owned by the REITs. Yes?

Comment: I'll repeat myself: yes.

Answer (score 1):

It tracks the returns of the REIT stocks in the REIT index, not the underlying properties.  The two vary from each other.  Green Street Advisors is a research firm that specializes in analysing the relative valuations of REIT stocks versus vs underlying properties, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up in the CFA Level 3 curriculum, where you learn about the ins and outs of various asset classes.

There are two commonly used indexes to track the performance of real estate investments in the US.

NAREIT is a monthly index of returns on publicly traded US REIT (Real Estate Investment Trusts) shares

NCREIF is an quarterly index of returns on commercial real estate properties. Because such properties are seldom sold, this index relies on periodic *appraisals* of the value of the properties.

The volatility of NAREIT is higher than the volatility of NCREIF. Some say this is because the stock market introduces extra volatility in REIT returns. They seem to be correlated to other Midcap and Smallcap stocks, and move in sympathy with them. Others say that the appraisals used in NCREIF result in artificial smoothing of NCREIF returns because appraisers tend to be conservative and do not adjust values quickly enough. I don't know how to tell who is right and there may be some truth to both views.

You can use one or the other index depending on your purpose. Direct investment in real estate => NCREIF, indirect investment via shares => NAREIT>